# SQL query to retrieve data which is in Parent and child relation in same table. Basically its a hierarchy table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, parent-child, hierarchy

can some one help me with query to get data which is parent - child relation in same table.it is an Hierarchy table

Ex : Table

```
   Parent_ID | Parent_Name | Child_ID | Child_Name
     1       |    A        |   2      |    B
     2       |    B        |   3      |    C
     3       |    C        |   4      |    Cc
     3       |    C        |   5      |    Ccc
     4       |    Cc       |   6      |    C_C
     1       |    A        |   7      |    D
     7       |    D        |   8      |    Dd
     9       |    E        |   10     |    Ee
     10      |    Ee       |   11     |    Eee
```

Data Relation of above table is

```
            For A -> B is child
                     For  B -> C is child
                           For  C -> Cc and Ccc are Childs
                                     For Cc -> C_C is child
```

want to retrieve data in following Table format :

```
    ParentId | Parent_Name | Child_Name | Child_Name | Child_Name | Child_Name
        1    |     A       |     B      |     C      |   Cc       |    Null
        1    |     A       |     B      |     C      |   Ccc      |    Null
        1    |     A       |     B      |     C      |   Cc       |    C_C
        1    |     A       |     D      |     Null   |   Null     |    Null
        1    |     A       |     D      |     Dd     |   Null     |    Null
        9    |     E       |     Ee     |     Null   |   Null     |    Null
        9    |     E       |     Ee     |     Eee    |   Null     |    Null
```

Another Example

Geography

```
     Parent_ID | Parent_Name | Child_ID | Child_Name
       1       |    Asia     |   2      |    India
       2       |    India    |   3      |    SouthIndia
       3       |  SouthIndia |   4      |    karnataka
       3       |  SouthIndia |   5      |    Kerela
       4       |  karnataka  |   6      |    Bengaluru
       1       |    Asia     |   7      |    Bangladesh
       7       |  Bangladesh |   8      |    Dhaka
       9       |  Srilanka   |   10     |    Colombo
       10      |  Colombo    |   11     |    Colombo district
       12      |North America|   13     |    Canada
       13      | Canada      |   14     |    Alberta
       13      | Canada      |   15     |    Ontario
       15      | Ontario     |   16     |    Toronto
```

Expecting as below

```
Parent_ID|Continent    | Country    | Zone       | State    | City

   1     |   Asia      |  India     | SouthIndia | karnataka| Bengaluru
   1     |   Asia      |  India     | SouthIndia | Kerela   |   
   1     |   Asia      | Bangladesh |            | Dhaka    |   
   1     |   Asia      | Srilanka   |            | Colombo  |Colombo district
  12     |NorthAmerica | Canada     |            | Alberta  |    
  12     |NorthAmerica | Canada     |            | Ontario  | Toronto
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you the expected result in table format. Also `Mysql` <> `SQL Server` so TAG the one you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, updated the expected results in table format

Comment: Your example table is invalid - it has bad FK references. Also, the key specification is not given.

Comment: **Please clarify,** 
Why is the last cell of first row is Null? If C_C is child to Cc then it should not be null. 
And what is the difference between 1st row and 3rd row ?

Comment: @Pieter, I don't think the example table is invalid. May be he don't have any FK, thus he is violating a major RDBMS rule. But that is his scenario out there and I'm sure he didn't ask for how to refactor his table design.

Rather, he wanted his desired result based on the existing data.

Comment: @autopilot, u r right, data is already there, i need to retrieve data in such a form where i can verify with my raw data which is in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not return your exact desired results as a few of those lines should have been considered in other rows (using posted data), consider the use of [self joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) all linked by `LEFT JOIN`.

Additionally, a subquery `WHERE` clause is needed to filter out original table 1's Parents that may be Children themselves.

[image: Parent-Child Left Joins]

```
SELECT t1.Parent_ID, t1.Parent_Name AS Parent, 
       t1.Child_Name AS Child1, t2.Child_Name AS Child2, 
       t3.Child_Name AS Child3, t4.Child_Name AS Child4    
FROM ParentChild t1 
LEFT JOIN ParentChild AS t2 ON t1.Child_Name = t2.Parent_Name
LEFT JOIN ParentChild AS t3 ON t2.Child_Name = t3.Parent_Name
LEFT JOIN ParentChild AS t4 ON t3.Child_Name = t4.Parent_Name

WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 sub.Parent_Name 
       FROM ParentChild sub 
       WHERE sub.Child_Name = t1.Parent_Name) IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Parent_ID   Parent  Child1  Child2  Child3  Child4
1           A       B       C       Cc      C_C
1           A       B       C       Ccc     
1           A       D       Dd              
9           E       Ee      Eee
```

Comment: @ Parfait, Thanks very much. will try this left join.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad I could help.